# Why am I getting a ValueError when using scipy solve_ivp?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I am getting this error:
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,1) into shape (4,)`
from my script below, which is trying to integrate some differential equations using interpolated data from a dataset. It might seem slightly nonsensical, since the integrated data will be the same as simply interpolating, but in a bigger project this seemed to me to be the best way to access the rate of change of these variables inside the integration function.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

def interpolateVariables(VariableData,t):
    FSH_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(VariableData[:,4], VariableData[:,[0]], axis = 0)
    LH_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(VariableData[:,4], VariableData[:,[1]], axis = 0)
    E2_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(VariableData[:,4], VariableData[:,[2]], axis = 0)
    P4_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(VariableData[:,4], VariableData[:,[3]], axis = 0)
    return FSH_interp(t), LH_interp(t), E2_interp(t), P4_interp(t)

def simulate_model(VariableData):
    tspan = [0,24]
    InitialValues = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
    result = solve_ivp(fun = lambda t, y: func(t,y, VariableData), t_span = tspan, y0 = InitialValues, method = "RK45")  
    return result
            
def func(t, y, VariableData):    
    FSH_int, LH_int, E2_int, P4_int = interpolateVariables(VariableData, t) 
    dFSH = FSH_int - y[0]
    dLH = LH_int - y[1] 
    dE2 = E2_int - y[2]
    dP4 = P4_int - y[3]
    dy = [dFSH, dLH, dE2, dP4] 
    print(dy)
    return dy

Variable_data = np.array([[6.5000000e+00, 4.8000000e+00, 1.9721760e+01, 1.8870000e-01, 0.0000000e+00],
       [6.2000000e+00, 4.1000000e+00, 2.9065080e+01, 1.8870000e-01, 2.0000000e+00],
       [7.4000000e+00, 4.3000000e+00, 3.8353920e+01, 1.8870000e-01, 4.0000000e+00],
       [6.1000000e+00, 4.9000000e+00, 4.8596160e+01, 1.8870000e-01, 6.0000000e+00],
       [4.8000000e+00, 5.2000000e+00, 1.0830624e+02, 3.4595000e-01, 8.0000000e+00],
       [3.6000000e+00, 6.0000000e+00, 1.8822840e+02, 2.2015000e-01, 1.0000000e+01],
       [1.2900000e+01, 4.8300000e+01, 2.6142228e+02, 7.5480000e-01, 1.2000000e+01],
       [6.3000000e+00, 7.2000000e+00, 6.4994640e+01, 3.7111000e+00, 1.4000000e+01],
       [4.0000000e+00, 5.9000000e+00, 1.8024708e+02, 1.7769250e+01, 1.8000000e+01],
       [3.2000000e+00, 5.3000000e+00, 2.0506272e+02, 1.8272450e+01, 2.0000000e+01],
       [2.9000000e+00, 3.0000000e+00, 1.4941140e+02, 1.3680750e+01, 2.2000000e+01],
       [3.4000000e+00, 4.8000000e+00, 8.6241840e+01, 3.1450000e+00, 2.4000000e+01]])
test = simulate_model(Variable_data)
```

Comment: Where's the full traceback?  You/we need to know where the error occurs.  I'm guessing `func` returns a `(4,1)` array (or equivalent tuple), while `y` is flat (4,) array.  Functions that don't conform to the `ivp` documented specs is a common problem.

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.